# Display terms on product page with shotrcode

Tags: php, functions, custom-taxonomy, shortcode

I need to add some shotrcodes for many taxonomies and I would like to display the value terms on a product page of woocommerce.
I tried with this but doesn't work, in this case the taxonomy name is "pagamento"

```
$terms = get_terms( 'pagamento' );
 if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo '<ul>';
     foreach ($terms as $term) {
     // $taxonomy name pagamento
     $pagamento = get_field('pagamento', $term->taxonomy.'_'.$term->term_id);
}
     echo '</ul>';
 }

add_shortcode( 'pagamento', 'na_display_pagamento' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this:

```
$terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'pagamento' ) );
```

Since 4.5.0, taxonomies should be passed via the ‘taxonomy’ argument in the $args, see: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/#description

**UPDATE:**

Your shortcode should looks like this:

```
function na_display_pagamento() {
    $output = "";
    $terms = get_terms( 'pagamento' );
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        $output .= '<ul>';
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            // $taxonomy name pagamento
            $pagamento = get_field( 'pagamento', $term->taxonomy.'_'.$term->term_id );
            if ( $pagamento ) {
                $output .= '<li>';
                    $output .= $pagamento;
                $output .= '</li>';
            }
        }
        $output .= '</ul>';
    }
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'pagamento', 'na_display_pagamento' );
```

Instead of echo the value, you can store the value in variable then return it.

Please see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply. I tried changing the line but nothing, I have not the value term in my shortcode :(

Comment: @MarcoFabris I just updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Tommy

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with:

function the_function_name() {
echo get_the_term_list( $product->ID, 'YOURTAXONOMY', '**Label Taxonomy:** ', ', ', '');
}
add_shortcode('mycustomshortcode', 'the_function_name');